# Как разместить круг так, чтобы он целиком не был виден на странице

Tags: html, css

Я сейчас пробую верстать figma макет.
Дело в том, что я не понимаю как мне сверстать этот круг, **который выходит за границы экрана**.

[image: Макет]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.round{
position:absolute;
right:-50px;
top:-50px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#fff;
border-radius:50%;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

```
html
    <div class="circle"></div>

css
.circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо! попробовал!

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с фоновым градиентом:

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 100px 100px, #ff4656 200px, black 201px) fixed;
}
```

Comment: Даже не думал о таком решении! Спасибо, попробую разобраться в этом.